# Problem with constructor ocilib::Resultset in Class

Tags: c++, ocilib

I have class:

```
#include "ocilib.hpp"
#include <string>

using namespace ocilib;

class Dao
{
public:

    Dao(std::string sqlQuery);

private:

    ocilib::Resultset rs;

};
```

and realisation of constructor:

```
Dao::Dao(std::string sql_query)
{
    Environment::Initialize();
    Connection con("tra", "la", "la");
    Statement st(con);
    st.Execute(sql_query);

    rs = st.GetResultset();
}
```

But VS2019 says:
**no default constructor exist for class "ocilib::Resultset".**

I want to store resultset object as variable of my DAO class and feel it during constructor. But looks like it is not a option to do like this.

What is right architecture to create DAO class with ocilib?

Comment: OCILIB Resultset class has a private constructor. By that your Dao class can't create it during construction. OCILIB Statement class is friend of Resultset and creates such objects which are returned by calls of e.g. GetResultset().

Answer (score 0):

At some other point in your program you try to call the default constructor of Doa, but as you have implemented your own constructor, there will be no default constructor in your Doa class.

First solution is to implemenent a default constructor with:

```
Doa()=default;
```

or

```
Doa() {}
```

if you have to do something special in `{}`.

A second solution is to find the place where you are trying to call the default constructor. A place might look like this:

```
Doa d;
```

Or even more hidden like:

```
std::vector<Doa> d(5);
```